# Entity Framework Single Pretty Error Message

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a lot of code that looks like this...

```
var employee = dbContext.Employees.Single(x => x.Id == dto.Id);
```

I use Single lookup to see if the record with gievn Id exists in the database before I edit it.

If the Id does not exist though I get an internal error and user doesn't know what happens.

How would I write clean code to catch this error and show a nice error message to user without using SingleOrDefault and checking null.

example (I could do this, but I would have to copy paste this code in 100+ locations)..

```
var employee = dbContext.Employees.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == dto.Id);
if(employee == null){
    throw new BusinessException("Could not find Employee");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this extension instead of `SingleOrDefault()`:

```
public static T SingleOrDefaultWithErrorMessage<T>(this DbSet<T> entities, Func<T, Boolean> predicate = null, String entityName = "the record") where T : class
{
    var entity = predicate != null
                    ? entities.SingleOrDefault(predicate)
                    : entities.SingleOrDefault();
    if (entity != null)
        return entity;

    throw new ApplicationException($"Could not find {entityName}.");
}
```

I added an optional parameter so that you can specify what the friendly name should be for the entity.

Keep in mind that if `predicate` is not specific enough you can still get the exception `Sequence contains more than one element` which will probably be confusing for your users. You could also choose to handle that exception in this extension method.

Comment: Is there a way to get entityName dynamically from T?

Comment: You could use `typeof(T).Name` but that's assuming your classes/entities have names that will make sense to your users.

Comment: I have a few different types besdies DbSet that would need to use this extension.  Is there a way to use ICollection instead of DBSet?  I have IQuerable, List and DBSet that all call .Single now

Comment: @TWilly you should be able to use it for those, test and see.

Comment: You could change `DbSet<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` and it will compile for all of the types you've mentioned.

Comment: k, getting there, this is looking great.  I also need predicate to be null, so you could call Single() without a predicate.  Adding in predicatred = null in function though gives me a attribute NotNull warning.

Comment: Please don't edit others' answers.  You're changing the intent of what I've posted and it may not in fact be a better answer.  As you mentioned you've now introduced a potential bug that was not part of my original answer for you.

Comment: My query performance is terrible now after switching to singleordefault.  Any ideas on how to keep singleordefault and keep the sample performance.  Here is a diff on the query.. http://imgur.com/a/wwvNx

Comment: this seems to be removed from the query when using the extension...

WHERE ([Extent1].[IsDeleted] <> 1) AND (N'980104' = [Extent1].[LocationId]) AND (1 = [Extent1].[AccountId]) AND (([Extent1].[ComplianceId] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Extent1].[ComplianceId] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))) ) AS [Limit1]

Comment: maybe this queries all records and then executes the predicate filter in memory?

Comment: You'd still have to include any other predicates to your query.  This isn't a wholesale replacement for any business logic you have besides the point.  Might want to review core EF stuff and IQuerable<T> in general.